# Which permission is needed to create a DDL trigger on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ddl, database-trigger

Which permission is needed to create a DDL trigger on a specific database (MS SQL Server)?

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because you didn't show any research effort. I'm sure a simple search ([Google](http://Google.com), [Bing](http://bing.com), [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com)) would have given you the answer; especially as such things are also within the product's documentation. Before asking a question, the volunteers expect you to do some due diligence. For questions like this, it's strongly expected that you try finding out the answer first.

Comment: Actually I did perform some research and found info about "ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER" permission and it looked like a permission for "ANY DATABASE" while I was looking for a specific database. I didn't realize it's the name of a permission which should be added to a specific database only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states:

> To create a DML trigger requires ALTER permission on the table or view on which the trigger is being created.
>
> To create a DDL trigger with server scope (ON ALL SERVER) or a logon trigger requires CONTROL SERVER permission on the server.
>
> To create a DDL trigger with database scope (ON DATABASE) requires ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER permission in the current database.